# Arrange nav tabs to single row in css/html

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

Im want to arrange all the nav tabs in a single row (in line with hr element).

I dont want any space between hr element and tabs.

After updating margin-top, for Technical Documentation tab, it seems fine, but for 1st tab , Products tab, still gap seems to be there between the hr.

[image]

**Gap in the 1st tab**

[image]

I have the below code like:

**UPDATED:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs search-results-navtab">
        <li class="active search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#products">Products <br/></a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#multilayer_inductors_series">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Technical
                <br/>Documentation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#smdpower_inductors_series">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#molding_inductors_series">Component
                <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Selector</a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#shieldedsmdpower_inductors_series">Quality</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <hr class="search-hr">
</div>
```

The Css is as:

```
.search-hr {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.search-results-navtab {
    padding-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 0px !important;
    background-color: white;
}

.search-list-class {
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Set the margin on the `hr` to `0`. `hr{margin:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution #1

Remove the `margin-top` value from the `hr` element.

```
hr {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

This will retain the `margin-bottom` value which you may need for spacing.

#### Solution #2

Alternatively, and I would recommend this, remove the `hr` element and declare `border-bottom` on a containing parent element of your list items (`li`), like `.nav`, then declare a `margin-bottom` property if you need bottom spacing.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs search-results-navtab">
        <li class="active search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#products">Products <br/></a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#multilayer_inductors_series">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Technical
                <br/>Documentation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#smdpower_inductors_series">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#molding_inductors_series">Component
                <br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Selector</a>
        </li>
        <li class="search-list-class">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#shieldedsmdpower_inductors_series">Quality</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Additional Styles Declared:**

```
.nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* adjust as per requirement */
}
```